# Sending multiple images as network input

Tags: keras

I am trying to give 3 separate grayscale images (1 channel each) as input for my network. How do I need to format it ?

I have looked into cv2 merge() but that seems to be for RGB channels. Can I use this the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the merge() function to do that (an RGB image is nothing else than a 3-channel array, it seems to be what you want, so no difference except that your channels have a different meaning). You can then use this as your input, without forgetting to specify the right input shape when building the network.